# Determining intersecting points between square and circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I unfortunately have spent too much time trying to solve this question, and have turned to you for help. The corner of my square has intersected some circle, and I need to move it out. I only know one side of the intersecting corner, and I need to know the other side of the corner in order to push it out of the circle. Can you help me?

[image: Sorry, I drew this in Paint...]

I know the side ("a"), I know the point ("P1"), and I need to find the length of side ("b").
`I also know the center points and radius of the circle (cx, cy, rad)`

So far, I can **find the point ("P2")** and ("P3) quite easily.

---P2(x, y) = P1(x, y - a)

**Now, to find ("@")**

---@ = atan2(P2y - cy, P2x - cx)

**Now, we can find P3:**

---P3x = cx + rad * cos(@)

---P3y = cy + rad * sin(@)

But even with all of this, I can't seem to find the length of ("b")! I would assume that if you knew the angle to the corner of the intersecting square's corner and the length of one side of that corner, you could find the other side!(confusing...) Can you? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to keep track of which coordinates we're at. We start at some point $P_1 = (-x,-y)$ on a circle of radius $r$. (I'm taking $x,y$ to both be positive.) . We move vertically a virtical distance $+a$, so that we land at point $P_2=(-x,-y+a)$. We then move a horizontal distance $-b$ to land at the point $(-x-b,-y+a)$ where the circle meets the square.

At this point, we don't know $b$. But we know that this point should lie on the circle. From the Pythagorean theorem we then have that the two points on the circle must satisfy $$ r^2 = x^2+ y^2=(-x-b)^2+(y-a)^2$$ If we multiply the last term out and cancel terms, we have 
$$ b^2+2b x +(a^2-2a y)=0$$ which is a quadratic equation in $b$. Solving this yields the final result
$$ \boxed{b = -x + \sqrt{x^2+2ay-a^2}}$$ As a check on this, note that if $a=0$ then one gets $b=0$ as it must (if the square has no length, you don't need to push it out). If $(x,y)=(0,a)$ (the bottom of the circle) then this gives $b=a$ (which again makes sense---the square occupies the entire quadrant of the circle.)

Comment: Umm... still don't really get it... I understand that this site usually suggests that the users give hints instead of answers, but this isn't homework I'm working on. I'm a developer. I get paid to write software, yet right now, I'm not writing any software because I've hit this mathematical roadblock. I've been wasting a couple hours on it, checked it out from every angle, and would really just like it figured out and out of my hair so I can move on. Thanks for the hint though, but I've thought of that already... :(

Comment: Fair enough. I'll elaborate. @WebWanderer

Comment: Thanks. I really do appreciate the focus. Didn't mean to come off as sour, I'm just frustrated.

Comment: Wait a minute... new angle...

Comment: Got it! About to post an answer

Comment: I'm about to post mine as well, so let's compare at that point.

Comment: Well, it wont let me post an answer because I'm new to the mathematics field of stack overflow. I'll post a comment with all of the text from my answer in it, but itll be ugly, here it goes...

Comment: So, I was able to find P2, which essentially contains the "y" value for the opposing end point of ("b"). I'll call this point P4.

We know `P4y = P2y`, which we have, we just need `P4x`. Here's how I did it:

    _y = cy + rad * sin@_
    
    _Now, theres going to be a new angle to
    _P4, so we need to find "@"_
    
    `@ = Math.asin((P2y - cy) / rad);`

    _Now that we have "@" for the point where
    P2y intersects the edge of the circle,
    we can find P4x_

    `P4x = cx + rad * Math.cos(@);`

    _Now, the length of "b" is P2x - P4x_

    `b = P2x - P4x;`

Comment: It'll probably be easier to move to chat, though we may not be able to do that either. (And I can't help with rep right now since I've used up all my votes for the day.) @WebWanderer

Comment: I dont mind rep, I just like answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15966/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-webwanderer).

Comment: @WebWanderer: Here's a thought: While you can't add answers, can you do edits to your question? In that case you could include a statement as to what you think the answer is.

Comment: good idea! Ill do that